# Using 'onload' alike function for td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a datatable in my django template, I have a td element in the table as shown below

```
 <td onclick="setColor('{{x.name}}')">{{x.name}}</td>`
```

I need this element to run the function 'setColor' everytime the webpage is loaded. I am unable to use onload here as oload is not valid for such elements, but I need to pass those parameters(because I am using a for loop here and this function gets called mutliple times in the loop with different {{x.id}}) which restricts me to only call this function from the exact td element. Is there a way that I could achieve this, so that the function gets called when the page loads and also the parameters are passed to the function?

Comment: Datatables has lots of events you can hook to when a page is changed, or data is updated, for example: http://m.datatables.net/reference/event/

Comment: you can call the onload method on body tag (you can't do this with td) and that method will do his job with the reuired tag (you need to point it by id ) HOPE THIS HELP.!!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Using the events you specified, how can I pass the parameters here? Can you please be more specific, if possible can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used django filter to solve this issue. The html code is given below:

```
{% load filters.py %}
 <td><span style="color:{{x.name|getNameColor}}">{{x.name}}</span></td>
```

I defined the getNameColor filter in my filters.py as shown below:

```
    @register.filter(name='getNameColor')
def getNameColor(value):
    if value == 'xxx':
        return '#f19203'
    elif value == 'yyy':
        return '#b3a800'
    elif value == 'zzz':
        return '#f45c42'
    elif value == 'uuu':
        return '#44cc00'
```

Useful link: http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

For who is searching a HTML/Javascript answer:

I had the same problem and found the solution in using custom attributes that I retrieve in the window.onload function. In my page I used the `<tr>` element, but this should work for a `<td>` also.

In the table:

```
<table>
    <tr name="my_row" foo="value1"><td>value1</td></tr>
    <tr name="my_row" foo="value2"><td>value2</td></tr>
</table>
```

In the window.onload function:

```
window.onload = function bar() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByName("my_row")
    for (row in rows) {
        var foo = row.getAttribute("foo")
        if (foo == "value1") {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```